# How do I convert this propositional formula to DNF?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

I have this propositional formula and want to convert it to DNF;
(¬V1 ∨ V2) ↔ (V1 → V2)

I'm guessing the first step is to do;
(¬V1) v (V2) <-> ¬(V1 v V2)

Then what is the next step, maybe something like this?

¬V1 v (V2 <-> ¬(V1 v V2)

What am I doing wrong or right so far? please give some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your proposition is always true. This is because the left term of the equivalence is true unless $V_1$ is true and $V_2$ is false, and the same is the case for the right term, so they are indeed equivalent.

(The corresponding DNF is, of course,
$$
(V_1 \wedge V_2) \vee (\neg V_1 \wedge V_2) \vee (V_1 \wedge \neg V_2) \vee (\neg V_1 \wedge \neg V_2).)
$$

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to bother but could you please show the steps you took to get to that DNF answer? Thank you so much

Comment: @ValentineJ: I think his steps was (1) know that the original formula is always true, (2) directly write down a DNF that is always true.